# How to plot a line graph with many lines from excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot the line graph with so many lines. I found the below basic commend to plot 1 line.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
location_3='C:\\Users\\Poon\\Downloads\\20211014_SBS_BEMS\\1043 final.csv'
csvfiles_3=glob.glob(location_3)
df7=pd.DataFrame()
for file_new_3 in csvfiles_3: 
    df7=pd.read_csv(file_new_3,skiprows=[0])
    print(df7)
    ax=plt.plot(df7.iloc[:, 1],df7.iloc[:, 2],'g')
```

But I need to plot more than 100 lines. Is there a faster way? Here are some of my data set in excel. There is more column than I show.

```
19/5/2019 0:00  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88   18.11   148.3115
19/5/2019 1:00  237.2667    64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88   18.11   148.3295
19/5/2019 2:00  238 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88   18.11   148.348
19/5/2019 3:00  238 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88   18.11   148.3672
19/5/2019 4:00  238 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88   18.11   148.4432
19/5/2019 5:00  238 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88   18.11   148.7437
19/5/2019 6:00  238 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88   18.11   149.064
19/5/2019 7:00  238 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88   18.11   149.3825
19/5/2019 8:00  238 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88   18.11   149.7037
19/5/2019 9:00  238.7833    64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88   18.11   150.0222
19/5/2019 10:00 239 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88   18.11   150.3422
19/5/2019 11:00 239 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88   18.11   150.6617
19/5/2019 12:00 239 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88   18.11   150.9813
19/5/2019 13:00 239 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88   18.11   151.3018
19/5/2019 14:00 239 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88   18.11   151.6213
19/5/2019 15:00 239 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88   18.11   151.94
19/5/2019 16:00 239.4167    64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88   18.11   152.2615
19/5/2019 17:00 240 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88   18.11   152.5812
19/5/2019 18:00 240 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88   18.11   152.8295
19/5/2019 19:00 240 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88   18.11   152.8608
19/5/2019 20:00 240 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88   18.11   152.8797
19/5/2019 21:00 240 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88   18.11   152.8962
19/5/2019 22:00 240 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88   18.11   152.9148
19/5/2019 23:00 240.05  64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88   18.11   152.9337
20/5/2019 0:00  241 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88   18.11   152.9508
```

So What I want is the x-axis to be the date, and Y-axis is column 2, then 3,4....until the end.

Moreover, the x-axis needs to reduce the number of plot ticks. Now there are too many plot ticks. How can I reduce them to "only year"? For example, there should be only 2019,2020,2021,2022.

Thanks a lots guys for your help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generate lines automatically, you can use a for cycle leaving out xaxis column like this (added example data for clearance, you can still read from your file):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

data = {
  "date": ['19/5/2019 0:00', '19/5/2019 1:00', '19/5/2020 2:00', '20/5/2021 3:00', '21/5/2022 1:00'],
  "colA": [237, 237, 238, 237, 240],
  "colB": [64.93, 64.94, 64.95, 65.52, 65.32],
  "colC": [644.93, 644.94, 644.95, 654.52, 654.32]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.date=pd.to_datetime(df.date)

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())

for col in df.columns:
    if not col == 'date':
        plt.plot(df.date, df[col], label=col) 
        
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Extra note: you can add base to YearLocator to change the frequency of years, for example, every 5 years would be:

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(base=5))
```

Comment: But I have more than 100 columns, it is still time consumption to set so many parameters.

Comment: You don't need to set the parameters manually, just read your data from Excel to dataframe:

df=pd.read_excel("inputfile.xlsx")

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to read the data (I just copied the data you provided and edited it for a couple of years and the data points to increase over time), then create the plots and finally add the timeline in years in the X-axis. The dataframe has Date as header for first date column and the other data columns are named A through G. The legend has some text, but you can edit it as you need.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df=pd.read_excel("inputfile.xlsx")
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

plt.plot(df.Date, df.A, label = "line 1")
plt.plot(df.Date, df.B, label = "line 2")
plt.plot(df.Date, df.C, label = "line 3")
plt.plot(df.Date, df.D, label = "line 4")
plt.plot(df.Date, df.E, label = "line 5")
plt.plot(df.Date, df.F, label = "line 6")
plt.plot(df.Date, df.G, label = "line 7")

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

**Output pic**

[image: output line plot]